# C++ complicated lambda expressions

Tags: c++, lambda

Im doing a bit crazy project so dont get scared Im creating some kind of lambda calculus in CPP. 
Anyway how do I make it work?

```
auto INC_ = [=](void *arg, void *(*n)(void*, void*))-> void * {return n(arg,arg); };
auto do_ = [=](void *arg1, void *arg2)-> void * {return arg1; };
INC(a,do_);
```

INC_ gets 2 arg however second arg is a lambda exp with 2 other arguments.

do_ do what must be done with 2 arg

However if I try to call it all together like in 3 line. I get wrong arguments error.

So the real question is how to pass 2 arg lambda so it executes properly?

Comment: What is with all the `void*`s?  C++ has a type system that is pretty useful.

Comment: _I get wrong arguments error._ And, exact error text is.. What, exactly?

Comment: Im required to get as close as possible to typeless code. I wrote at the beginning that its a bit crazy ;) 
 If you can show example on int i can try to copy it into fancy void*

Comment: Ah.  If you want *typeless" code you should use generic code (templates).  See this reworked example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d3d1c246a9a0564

Comment: "Function cant be called with the given arg list" ;) And more after comp:
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
note: class does not define an 'operator()' or a user defined conversion operator to a pointer-to-function or reference-to-function that takes appropriate number of arguments

Comment: Oh i written template version already :D Now im just having some fun

Comment: @Gryfit 1) You should not add question-related information to the comments. You should [edit] the question, and include it there. 2) That is still, not complete error message. I said that you need to copy-paste it, instead of paraphrasing it. Complete error message about _wrong arguments_ specify what arguments were expected, and what was passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lambda is not a function pointer.

```
auto INC_ = [=](void *arg, void *(*n)(void*, void*))-> void * {return n(arg,arg); };
auto do_ = [=](void *arg1, void *arg2)-> void * {return arg1; };
INC(a,do_);
```

The second argument to `INC_` is a function pointer.

A stateless lambda can be converted to a function pointer with compatible signature.

Once there is state, this is not possible.  `[=]` makes it stateful, even though it doesn't capture anything.

In addition, don't use function pointers in typeless code.

Try this:

```
int a = 0;
auto INC_ = [](auto arg, auto n) {return n(arg,arg); };
auto do_ = [](auto arg1, auto arg2) {return arg1; };
std::cout << INC(a,do_) << "\n";
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a94ba30d0f05a4c9).